# Attempting to change two public int values, but when returned are untouched

Tags: java

If it's not apparent by the question, I'm not very amazing at java yet. I'm just playing tonight with a few fundamentals that I would need to be comfortable with for a little idea I have, but have hit a problem. I may just be tired and missing something, if so I apologize.

This is the code in the Main.java class:

```
private int h,w;

public static void main(String args[]){
    Main inst = new Main();
    inst.Frame();
    Second s = new Second();


}

public void Frame(){
    this.h = 200;
    this.w = 200;
}



public int getWidth(){
    return w;
}
public int getHeight(){
    return h;
}
```

It's a very basic program, just aiming to create two ints (h,w) and change their values in Frame(), and then using the two methods at the bottom return the 200 values in class 2.

This is second.java:

```
Second(){
    this.Window();
}

public void Window(){
    System.out.println("window()");
    Main win = new Main();

    int width = win.getWidth();
    int height = win.getHeight();


    System.out.println("width and height "+width+height);

}
```

The output in Window() simply gives two zeroes. this is countered by changing the values the moment they are created (Public int w=200,h=200), but this is not what I'm looking to do, as it needs to be changed at a further point.

Any ideas how to get the changes done in Frame() to appear in the Window ints? Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
`Second(Main m){
   this.Window(m);
 }

 public void Window(Main m){
    System.out.println("window()");
    Main win = m;

    int width = win.getWidth();
    int height = win.getHeight();


    System.out.println("width and height"+width+height);

  }`
```

Answer (score 2):

You're creating two independent instances of Main, each with their own h & w values.  You change the values of the first instance, then print them from the second, unchanged instance.

You probably want to pass your Main instance as an argument to the Second constructor, so they can share the same data.

Comment: Thanks, I'm still getting to understand instances so missed it. I'm just trying to play about with methods linking to each other and such at the minute, appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have a void method, not a constructor. Remove the `void` keyword.